# How to create an HTML-based AIR app from Flash Builder?

Tags: ios, flash, mobile, air, flash-builder

Since it is not possible to run code in child swfs under iOS I am trying to have the top of my app be an HTML page which chooses which swf to load. I am building in Flash Builder.

The problem is that in the app.xml the value specified in

```
<initialWindow>
  <content>value</content>
</initialWindow>
```

gets automatically overwritten with the name of the project swf. I want to specify this value as an html page. Can this be done in FlashBuilder or do I have to do command-line AIR?

Thanks,

--S

Answer (score 0):

You should try another approach.
It is not possible to create mobile HTML-based air application because they [are not supported](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-8000.html).
You can display HTML pages using StageWebView object, but on iOS swf files won't be rendered.